# Uncaught typeEroor: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code with which I am trying to truncate the `innerHTML` of elements with an id of `title`:

```
<script>
    var titles = document.querySelectorAll("#title")

    function truncate(input) {
        if (input.length > 10)
            return input.substring(0, 10) + '...';
        else
            return input;
    };


    for (i = 0; i < titles[i].length; i++) {
        titles[i].innerHTML = truncate(titles[i])
    }
</script>

<div class="container mx-auto px-4 mt-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karma">



    <div class="w3-row-padding">

        <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <h5 class="card-title" id="title"><b>Hfe</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">dvcd</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <h5 class="card-title" id="title"><b>nbvn</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">vbnv</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <h5 class="card-title" id="title"><b>New post</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">New</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <h5 class="card-title" id="title"><b>Again</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">mnmbmbm</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <h5 class="card-title" id="title"><b>mn,</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">m</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <h5 class="card-title" id="title"><b>Reacting to the the funniest breakup texts</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">sfd</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <h5 class="card-title" id="title"><b>.m,m,</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">nvb, ,bmvbcv
                    vcnbcm mbnmnbm,.mnm,,m.m,m,</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


            <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
            <div class="w3-container w3-white">
                <h5 class="card-title" id="title"><b>DVGGGGGGGGGGHDGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</b></h5>
                <p class="card-text">GGGGGG</p>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

It gives me this **error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: `titles[i]` is getting one of the elements, not the whole array. The element, in this case, does not have a length. titles.length has a length though.

Comment: You can not have the same id for multiple objects.

Comment: A side note: The console displays also the line number, where the error raised. This makes it easier to spot the possible source of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things. First your title is returning the object, not the string. As it is an HTML element.
In the loop `titles[i].length` is checking for length of current HTML element which is not possible, length checks for Array or string length. So you should use `titles.length` which is an array collection of HTML elements.

This also means for truncate function, you are sending an HTML element to the function, not the string. To pass the string, you should target `b` element inside the title, so you do not omit the HTML structure, and then get the `textContent` for further processing -> `const text = titles[i].querySelector('b').textContent`

So your function will look like this:

```js
var titles = document.querySelectorAll("#title")

function truncate(input) {
   if (input.length > 10)
      return input.substring(0,10) + '...';
   else
      return input;
};


for(i=0; i < titles.length; i++){
    const text = titles[i].querySelector('b').textContent
    titles[i].querySelector('b').textContent =  truncate(text)
}
```

```html
   <div class="container mx-auto px-4 mt-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karma">



       <div class="w3-row-padding">

  <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <h5 class="card-title" id = "title"><b>Hfe</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">dvcd</p>

      </div>
    </div>
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <h5 class="card-title" id = "title"><b>nbvn</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">vbnv</p>

      </div>
    </div>
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <h5 class="card-title" id = "title"><b>New post</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">New</p>

      </div>
    </div>
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <h5 class="card-title" id = "title"><b>Again</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">mnmbmbm</p>

      </div>
    </div>
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <h5 class="card-title" id = "title"><b>mn,</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">m</p>

      </div>
    </div>
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <h5 class="card-title" id = "title"><b>Reacting to the the funniest breakup texts</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">sfd</p>

      </div>
    </div>
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <h5 class="card-title" id = "title"><b>.m,m,</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">nvb, ,bmvbcv
vcnbcm mbnmnbm,.mnm,,m.m,m,</p>

      </div>
    </div>
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-margin-bottom">


      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com//w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Card image" style="">
      <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <h5 class="card-title" id = "title"><b>DVGGGGGGGGGGHDGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</b></h5>
        <p class="card-text">GGGGGG</p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop use `titles.length` and not `titles[i].length`. `titles[i]` will give the element and no element has `.length` method associated with it. Hence the error